# 11- Proof method in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

A Dutch bank account consists of 9 digits e.g.: `1334.36.915`.
To check whether the bank account is valid we use the so called ‘`11-proef`’ (11-test).
In this test each digit is multiplied with its place in the row.The result of this multiplication is added up.

```
(1*9)+(3*8)+(3*7)+(4*6)+(3*5)+(6*4)+(9*3)+(1*2)+(5*1) = R
```

This result has to be dividable by 11. That means the remainder of the division must be 0.
If the `R` is dividable by 11 the bank account number is valid!

Can someone help with this question?

Comment: uhm, no it doesn't... postbank has any amount of digits, and now we're on the european standard of IBAN. Also bank accounts were possible to have 10 digits before the iban transition.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets This looks like a homework. It does not matter :)

Comment: In that case Bojidar Conev should inform his teacher that his material is outdated ;)

Answer (score 1):

A Dutch bank account number does not consist of 9 digits anymore, we now use Iban Numbers. If you want to do a check on it, you should have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Validating_the_IBAN and implement that check.

For now, you can however still to the 11-check on the last 9 or 10 digits, but it's not guaranteed that will still work for new bank accounts in the future.

If you still want to do a 11-check, you can create a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION elfproof (accountnummer IN varchar2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
      multiplier int:= 10;
      outcome varchar2(10);
      total int := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. 9
   LOOP

     multiplier := multiplier - 1;
      total := total + (multiplier * TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (accountnummer, i, 1)));

   END LOOP;

   IF MOD (total, 11) = 0
   THEN
      outcome := 'good';
   ELSE
      outcome := 'bad';
   END IF;

   return outcome;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives the remainder of division on 11:

```
SELECT 
    MOD (SUM (TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (str, LEVEL, 1)) * (10 - LEVEL)), 11) remdiv11
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            REPLACE ('1334.36.915', '.') str 
        FROM 
            DUAL
    ) d
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (str)
```

and IBAN check;) :

```
SELECT 
    DECODE (MOD (TO_NUMBER (LISTAGG (n, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY l)), 97), 1, 'OK', 'Fail') AS iban_check
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            TO_CHAR (CASE 
                        WHEN ASCII (c) >= 65 THEN ASCII (c) - 55 
                        ELSE ASCII (c) - 48 END) n, c, l
        FROM 
            (    
                SELECT 
                    SUBSTR (str, LEVEL, 1) c, LEVEL l
                FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            SUBSTR (s, 5) || SUBSTR (s, 1, 4) str
                        FROM 
                            (
                                SELECT 
                                    REPLACE ('GB82 WEST 1234 5698 7654 32', ' ') s 
                                FROM
                                    DUAL
                            )
                    )
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (str)
            )
    )
```

Comment: wheres the INDENTATION ? ;)

Comment: @NullException You can IDENT me ;) Use the Edit button

Comment: I agree, I should I(N)DENT you. You missed the N.

Comment: @NullException I have approved it, but you know, that this is a style. Everything was formated with Toad formater. For me the previous was better.

Comment: I indented it in Notepad++ manually. Toad produces another output, at least for me. Rollback the edit if you want to, suggestion was made, whether you accept it or not.